# How can I draw with coordinates of intersection in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates, intersections

When using pgfplots, the command `\pgfgetlastxy` works well without axis environment and with axis environment set as default.

But it is hard getting the correct coordinate of intersecting, when setting something with the axis environment.

[image]

I want to get the result with the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines*=none,axis y line=center, axis x line=center,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north east,xshift=1mm},
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east,yshift=1mm},
xmin=-0.2,ymin=-0.15,
xmax=1.5,ymax=1.5,
%xtick={1},ytick={1},
restrict y to domain=0:1.2,
height=6cm,width=5cm,
enlargelimits=false]
\node[below left,black] at (axis cs:0,0) {$O$};

\addplot[name path global=x2,blue,smooth,samples=500,domain=0:1.2] %
        {x^2} node[pos=0.75,sloped,yshift=-6pt]{$y=x^2$};
\addplot[name path global=genx,red,smooth,samples=500,domain=0:1.2] %
        {sqrt(x)} node[pos=0.75,sloped,yshift=6pt]{$x=y^2$};

\def\vlvalue{0.4}; %x  interval:[x,x+dx]
\def\intvlen{0.1}; %dx
\path[draw=none,name path=lx] (axis cs:\vlvalue,0)--(axis cs:\vlvalue,1.2); %x
\path[draw=none,name path=ldx] (axis cs:\vlvalue+\intvlen,0)--(axis cs:\vlvalue+\intvlen,1.2);%x+dx
%
\path[name intersections={of=x2 and lx,name=k}] (axis cs:\vlvalue,0)--(k-1); 
\path(k-1)  \pgfextra{\pgfgetlastxy{\kx}{\ky}     %%no ;
              \global\let\kx\kx %
              \global\let\ky\ky};
\draw[blue,dashed] (axis cs:\vlvalue,0)--(\kx,\ky);
\path[name intersections={of=genx and lx,name=m}] (axis cs:\vlvalue,0)--(m-1);
\path(m-1)  \pgfextra{\pgfgetlastxy{\mx}{\my}     %%no ;
              \global\let\mx\mx %
              \global\let\my\my};
%draw from (k-1) to (\vlvalue+\intvlen,\ky)
\draw[red] (\kx,\ky)--(axis cs:\vlvalue+\intvlen,\ky); % % %wrong \ky
%draw rectangle 
\fill[cyan!5] (k-1) rectangle (axis cs:\vlvalue+\intvlen,\my); % %wrong \my
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to draw a rectangle `\fill[cyan!5] (k-1) rectangle (axis cs:\vlvalue+\intvlen,\my);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `\pgfgetlastxy` for this, you can work directly with the intersections and with the `calc` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[%
axis lines*=none,axis y line=center, axis x line=center,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-0.2,ymin=-0.15,
xmax=1.5,ymax=1.5,
restrict y to domain=0:1.2,
height=6cm,width=5cm,
enlargelimits=false]
\node[below left,black] at (axis cs:0,0) {$O$};

\addplot[name path global=x2,blue,smooth,samples=500,domain=0:1.2] %
        {x^2} node[pos=0.75,sloped,yshift=-6pt]{$y=x^2$};
\addplot[name path global=genx,red,smooth,samples=500,domain=0:1.2] %
        {sqrt(x)} node[pos=0.75,sloped,yshift=6pt]{$x=y^2$};

\def\vlvalue{0.4}; %x  interval:[x,x+dx]
\def\intvlen{0.1}; %dx
\path[name path=lx] (axis cs:\vlvalue,0)--(axis cs:\vlvalue,1.2);

\draw [
    red,
    name intersections={of=x2 and lx,name=k},
    name intersections={of=genx and lx,name=m}
    ] (k-1) rectangle ($(m-1)+(axis direction cs:\intvlen,0)$); % %wrong \my
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: jake, thank you, you must be a magician! i study your answers for a day, and cannot get the coordinate of intersection. but how get the correct \ky, \my etc.?

Comment: @huizhanwang: Take a look at [Coordinates of intersections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38461/coordinates-of-intersections). You hardly ever need that approach for drawing something, though. It's mainly useful for labelling intersections.