# Identify axis points in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have written the following code which basically plots a binomial distribution as a function of its parameter.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
domain=0:1,
axis lines=left,
grid=both,
xlabel=$\theta$,
ylabel=$L(\theta)$
]
\addplot[smooth,thick,black]
{factorial(50)/(factorial(10)*factorial(40)) *x^10 *(1-x)^40};
\addplot[smooth,dashed,red]
{0.0699};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces the following figure.

[image: output]

As you can see the peak is at 0.2, and the value of the function at this point is a little over 0.13. The red-dashed line at 0.0699 merely represents half that height.

My question now is, whether I could identify those two points in the x-axis, which I have labelled as theta, where this dashed line intersects the function. It is quite a difficult calculation if it is performed manually and I was hoping I could see it graphically.

Comment: Mathematica clamis that `\theta \approx 0.1375322` and `\theta \approx 0.2741498`. Now you can draw the two line segments.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thank you. Perhaps then, there is no way to do it in Tikz? For the line segments I would have to use the draw command, yes?

Comment: I know vertually nothing about TikZ, sorry, so I can't tell you.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg That's alright. Thanks for your input.

Comment: [Coordinates of intersections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38461) is related at least.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried to follow the suggestions of the thread but I fear I am too new of a user to do so successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
domain=0:1,
axis lines=left,
grid=both,
clip=false,
xlabel=$\theta$,
ylabel=$L(\theta)$
]
\addplot[name path=curve,smooth,thick,black]
{factorial(50)/(factorial(10)*factorial(40)) *x^10 *(1-x)^40};
\addplot[name path=line,smooth,dashed,red]
{0.0699};
\path[name intersections={of=curve and line, by={a,b}}];
\draw[dashed] 
  (a) -- (a|-{axis cs:0,0}) node[anchor=north,font=\tiny] {$\theta_1$};
\draw[dashed] 
  (b) -- (b|-{axis cs:0,0}) node[anchor=north,font=\tiny] {$\theta_2$};
\node[fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (a) {};
\node[fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (b) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to use the `intersections` library and `name path` to (well...) name the paths; then you can let TikZ calculate the intersection points; using `name intersections` you can assign them names for further actions.

To get the coordinates of the intersection points, you can apply [`Jake's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38572/3954) to [Coordinates of intersections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38461/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\transformxdimension[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@x@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
}
\newcommand\transformydimension[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@y@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@y)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y}
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill},
domain=0:1,
axis lines=left,
grid=both,
clip=false,
xlabel=$\theta$,
ylabel=$L(\theta)$
]
\addplot[name path global=curve,smooth,thick,black]
{factorial(50)/(factorial(10)*factorial(40)) *x^10 *(1-x)^40};
\addplot[name path global=line,smooth,dashed,red]
{0.0699};
\path[name intersections={of=curve and line, by={a,b}}];
\node[anchor=south] at (a)
  {
    \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
    \transformxdimension{\macrox}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},%
    \transformydimension{\macroy}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult} 
  };
\node[anchor=north west] at (b)
  {
    \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
    \transformxdimension{\macrox}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},%
    \transformydimension{\macroy}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult} 
  };

\draw[dashed] 
  (a) -- (a|-{axis cs:0,0}) node[anchor=north,font=\tiny] {$\theta_1$};
\draw[dashed] 
  (b) -- (b|-{axis cs:0,0}) node[anchor=north,font=\tiny] {$\theta_2$};
\node[fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (a) {};
\node[fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (b) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but how can I identify the points in the x axis, theta1 and theta2?

Comment: @JohnK What do you mean "identify"? Do you want to get the coordinates of those points?

Comment: Sorry. I meant the coordinates of these points.

Comment: @JohnK Please see my updated answer.