# Annotating specific points in tikz plot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm plotting a exponential function and I need to point out some specific values in my plot.

Point name (x;y)

Point N1 (2;50)

Point N2 (4;25)

I'm trying to follow [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228896/identify-axis-points-in-tikz) but I am not getting any success

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
    domain=10:1,
    axis lines=left,
    grid=both,
    clip=false,
    xlabel=$Tempo (dias)$,
    ylabel=$Atividade (Ci)$
]
\addplot[name path=curve,smooth,thick,black]{100*exp(-x*ln(2)/2)};
\addplot[name path=line,smooth,dashed,red]{50};
\path[name intersections={of=curve and line, by={a}}];
\draw[dashed] 
  (a) -- (a|-{axis cs:0,0}) node[anchor=north,font=\tiny] {$N=1$};
\node[fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (a) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Note that I only tried pointing N1 here, and even that doesn't work.
Also, I dont want do plot a line just to make the intersection, but I don't know how to do in another way.

Any advice?

Comment: Where you like to have written specific value? At point determined by intersection of curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to Alenanno answer, with nodes name at nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
X/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.5pt, 
            label={[font=\scriptsize]above right:#1},
            node contents={}}
                    ]
\begin{axis}[
    domain=10:1,
    axis lines=left,
    grid=both,
    clip=false,
    xlabel=\textit{Tempo (dias)},
    ylabel=\textit{Atividade (Ci)}
]
\addplot[smooth,thick,black]{100*exp(-x*ln(2)/2)};
%
\draw[dashed] (1,50) -- (2,50) node[X={$N=1$}] -- (2,3);
\draw[dashed] (1,25) -- (4,25) node[X={$N=2$}] -- (4,3);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above code I consider, that the recent `pgfplots` package is avaliable. In case, that it is before version 1.11, than in coordinates should be added `axis cs:`, something like `(axis cs:1,25)`.

[image]

Comment: real nice output! thank you! I'm definitely trying once my tex installation its done (just removed everything to update...)

Comment: Done! tex updated and pgfplotsset is now 1.13. Your code works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd need intersections to do a good job. There would be other solutions but the ones I can think of require even more code than mere intersections. Still, in your case you don't even need intersections. You can just draw the lines.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={fill=black, circle, inner sep=1.5pt},
    nod/.style={sloped, at start, xshift=3mm, font=\scriptsize, above},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
    domain=10:1,
    axis lines=left,
    grid=both,
    clip=false,
    xlabel=Tempo (dias),
    ylabel=Atividade (Ci)
]
\addplot[name path=curve,smooth,thick,black]{100*exp(-x*ln(2)/2)};

\draw[dashed] (2,5) -- (2,50) coordinate[dot] node[nod] {$N=1$} -- (1,50);

\draw[dashed] (4,5) -- (4,25) coordinate[dot] node[nod] {$N=2$} -- (1,25);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With pgflots version 1.133 is not need to use `axis cs:` in coordinates anymore :-)

Comment: @Zarko Didn't know about that! Very convenient. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Houston, we have a problem: I can't compile if pgfplotsset compat isn't set to 1.9 and, using your answer, the points aren't in the right place. Let me upload a picture of it

Comment: @Zarko and Alenanno: You may also want to comment on using math mode in the axis labels. They shouldn't be in math mode, as they're just text.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @erickfis Use `axis cs:2,5` as in the original version of this answer, then it should work also with `compat=1.9`.

Comment: @erickfis Aren't you able to use `1.13`? Why `1.9`?

Comment: updating my tex distribution now on dog slow internet. I'm using this metod: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu - I have just removed everything and cannot try anything until its complete =( Tomorrow I'll be back with news

Comment: @erickfis As Torbjørn T. said, use `(axis cs: ...)` for now.

Comment: Done! tex updated and pgfplotsset is now 1.13. Your code works like a charm. Thank you!