The hatch pattern created by the fill command does not respect the defined space
In picture below I am struggling with \fill for AEHD shape:
  \fill[pattern={north east lines}, pattern color=gray] 
     (pointD|-0,0) -- (pointD) -- (pointH) -- (pointH|-0,0) -- cycle;

which produces hatches which slightly ross the brown line of the function x^2. It is an internal rounding error of the Tex engine? I also tried using the clipp environment but unfortunately also with the same result.
On the other hand I am using the same command for EFGH shape and it works well.
MNWE:
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, interaction: nonstopmode }

% References:
% [1] Rektorys2011 page~65
% [2] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38461/
% [3] https://github.com/Chris7462/TikZ/blob/master/manual/TikZcheatsheet.pdf

\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\xMin}{-0.5}%
\newcommand{\xMax}{+5.0}%
\newcommand{\yMin}{-0.5}%
\newcommand{\yMax}{+8.0}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, scale=1,
  myarrow/.style={-{Latex[round, scale=2.5, length=2, width=3]}},
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19348/how-to-draw-a-line-passing-through-a-point-and-perpendicular-to-another
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm
]
% Kartézská soustava souřadnic:
\draw[myarrow] (\xMin-0.5,0) -- (\xMax+0.5,0) node[right] {\(x\)};
\draw[myarrow] (0,\yMin-0.5) -- (0,\yMax+0.5) node[above] {\(y\)};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {\(0\)};

% Body:
  \coordinate (S) at (4,2.5);
        
  \draw[
    color=Coral4, ultra thick,
    domain=0:2.3, 
    variable=\x,
    xscale=2,yscale=1.5,
    name path=funcx2, 
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.20 with {
        \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {};   % point D
        \coordinate (pointD) at (0,0);
      },
      mark=at position 0.45 with {
        \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {}; % point H
        \coordinate (pointH) at (0,0);
      },
      mark=at position 0.70 with {
        \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {}; % point G
        \coordinate (pointG) at (0,0);
      },
      mark=at position 0.93 with {
        \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {}; % point C
        \coordinate (pointC) at (0,0);
      }
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  ] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x}) node[xshift=-2.1em] {\(f(x)=x^2\)};

  % points on x-axis:
  \draw[ultra thick] (pointD|-0,0) 
    node[yshift=-0.71em] {\(1\)}                % lower text 
    node[xshift=-0.5em,yshift=+0.51em] {A}      % upper text    
    -- (pointD) node[above] {D};
  \draw[thick] (pointH|-0,0) 
    node[yshift=-0.81em] {\(x\)}                % lower text
    node[xshift=-0.5em,yshift=+0.51em] {E}      % upper text  
    -- (pointH) node[left] {H};
  \draw[dashed] (pointG|-0,0) 
    node[yshift=-0.71em] {\(x+h\)}              % lower text
    node[xshift=+0.5em,yshift=+0.51em] {F}      % upper text  
    -- (pointG) node[right] {G};
  \draw[ultra thick] (pointC|-0,0) 
    node[yshift=-0.71em] {\(3\)}                % lower text
    node[xshift=+0.5em,yshift=+0.51em] {B}      % upper text  
    -- (pointC) node[left] {C};

  % Add hatched area between points A, E, H, and D:
  \fill[pattern={north east lines}, pattern color=gray] 
    (pointD|-0,0) -- (pointD) -- (pointH) -- (pointH|-0,0) -- cycle;

  % Add hatched area between points E, F, G, and H:
  \fill[pattern={north west lines}, pattern color=gray] 
    (pointH|-0,0) -- (pointH) -- (pointG) -- (pointG|-0,0) -- cycle;

  \fill [black] (0,0) node[above, xshift = 6pt] {O} circle (2pt);  % point O
  \fill [black] (pointD|-0,0) circle (2pt);  % point A
  \fill [black] (pointC|-0,0) circle (2pt);  % point B
  \fill [black] (pointC)      circle (2pt);  % point C
  \fill [black] (pointD)      circle (2pt);  % point D
  \fill [black] (pointH|-0,0) circle (2pt);  % point E
  \fill [black] (pointG|-0,0) circle (2pt);  % point F
  \fill [black] (pointG)      circle (2pt);  % point G
  \fill [black] (pointH)      circle (2pt);  % point H

  \draw[dashed] (pointG) -- (pointG-|pointH) -- (pointH); 
  \draw[ultra thick]  (pointD|-0,0) -- (pointC|-0,0); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

enter code here



Replace ultra thick by line width=0pt and you will see that the EFGH shape is also bad. The segments between D and H and between H and G are not straight !

@Paul Gaborit: OMG. You are right. Do you have some idea how to replace stright line between D an H with curve defined by function x^2?

Since you're already loading PGFplots and its fillbetween library why aren't you using it for this task? But still, even with just TikZ the library can be used to split the curve at D, H and G and use the segments in a new path. The spath3 library can be used as well. (They both have their advantages and disadvantages.) Of course, replotting the segments is possible as well but needs you guessing the x values for those points … or produce those points differently.

Keeping with your approach, you could also place more coordinates between D and H as well as between H and G and use those for the pattern. Placing the pattern in the background makes the curve hide any imperfection.

That said, why aren't you simply placing the dots at (<x>, <x>²) and then just replot the segments. That could be much easier as well since you then know all the coordinates.

Going with my cheaty approach – there are plenty of pgfplots, fillbetween or spath3 solutions on this site already –, this places a few coordinates between D and H as well as between H and G.
These are used for the hatched path. (I'm using a plot here since it makes it much easier to use nodes' centers without specifying the anchor everytime.)
With the backgrounds library and the on background layer key, these patterns will be placed behind the curve.
Code
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%  \usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % ← !
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  dot on line/.style={
    shape = circle, fill = black,
    inner sep = +1.5pt, outer sep=+0pt}}
\pgfset{
  decoration/place dot/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{
    mark=at position #1 with {%
      \node[dot on line](#2){};
      \path[reset cm] node[dot on line] (#3) at (#2|-0,0) {};}},
  decoration/multiple coords/.style args={#1/#2}{
    mark=between positions #1 with {\coordinate
      (#2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number});}}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\xMin}{-0.5}%
\newcommand{\xMax}{+5.0}%
\newcommand{\yMin}{-0.5}%
\newcommand{\yMax}{+8.0}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, scale=1,
  myarrow/.style={-{Latex[round, scale=2.5, length=2, width=3]}},
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19348/how-to-draw-a-line-passing-through-a-point-and-perpendicular-to-another
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm
]
% Kartézská soustava souřadnic:
\draw[myarrow] (\xMin-0.5,0) -- (\xMax+0.5,0) node[right] {\(x\)};
\draw[myarrow] (0,\yMin-0.5) -- (0,\yMax+0.5) node[above] {\(y\)};

% Body:
\coordinate (S) at (4,2.5);
      
\draw[
  color=Coral4, ultra thick,
  domain=0:2.3, 
  variable=\x,
  xscale=2,yscale=1.5,
  name path=funcx2, 
  decoration={
    markings,
    place dot=.2/pointD/pointA,
    multiple coords=.25 and .4 step .05/pointD,
    place dot=.45/pointH/pointE,
    multiple coords=.5 and .65 step .05/pointH,
    place dot=.7/pointG/pointF,
    place dot=.93/pointC/pointB,
  },
  postaction=decorate
] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x}) node[xshift=-2.1em] {\(f(x)=x^2\)};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[pattern={north east lines}, pattern color=gray]
    plot[sharp cycle, samples at = {D, D2, D3, D4, H, E, A}] (point\x);
  
  \fill[pattern={north west lines}, pattern color=gray]
        plot[sharp cycle, samples at = {H, H6, H7, H8, G, F, E}] (point\x);
\end{scope}

\draw[ultra thick] plot[samples at = {D, A, E, F, B, C}](point\x);
\node[dot on line] (pointO){};

\draw[name prefix=point, dashed] (G) -| (H) (G) -- (F);
\draw (pointH) -- (pointE);
\foreach \pos/\p/\t in {above right/O, above left/A, above/D, left/H, right/G, left/C,
                        above left/E, above right/F, above right/B,
                        below left/O/0, below/A/1, below/E/x, below/F/x+h, below/B/3}
  \node also[label={[inner sep=+.15em, text height=.8\ht\strutbox]\pos:$\t$}](point\p);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


The issue is that shape AEHD is not correctly defined. It uses straight lines between points. It is necessary to incorporate curve part into fill comment like it is shown below:
  % Add hatched area between points A, E, H, and D
  \fill[pattern={north east lines}, pattern color=gray] 
    (pointD|-0,0) -- % point A 
    (pointD) -- plot[domain=1:1.5,samples=10,xscale=2,yscale=1.5] function {x*x} -- 
    (pointH) -- (pointH|-0,0) % point E
    -- cycle;

What is interesting that it works well if the domain is not exactly 1:2.3 as it is specified but maximum is little bit lower (e.g.) 1:1.5. If the domain is restricted to 1:2.3 the filled shape is little bit bigger.
